# Adding a document in Firestore from web app is not working and not returning an error

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Suddenly my code for adding new documents to Firestore is not working and not returning an error. I thought perhaps it was a network issue but Authentication and creating new users is working fine. My network connection is also quite solid.

[EDIT] I've switched on debug mode and a call to Firestore is made with a documentChange request and the correct data fields. The document is never created though. I am on the latest Firestore release.

I tried this simplified add to my collection:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('biff').add({
    boff: 0,
    baff: 5
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.error('There was an error uploading a file to Cloud Storage:', error);
  });
```

Here are my security rules: (I also tried completely public writing)

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

There are no error messages generated and the new document never appears in my collection. I can authenticate and create new users. Is it possible that authentication is live but somehow my firebase SDK thinks that there is no connection to firestore so its queueing up the documnent writes?

[UPDATE] I noticed that an earlier alpha version of my frontend was still able to write new documents. When I listed the projects firebase knew about in the CLI it listed an older firebase project. So I did 'firebase use --add' and chose my new firebase project and then did a 'firebase init' to reset everything except my index.html. I then did a 'firebase deploy' and lo and behold my deployed version is able to write new documents. My localhost version still is not able to write them though. So very odd. So I am half way there with a solution. All ideas welcome on whats happening on my local machine to stop writes still ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once I used a button instead of a form submit to trigger the routine with the document.add then it all worked from localhost, server and mobile. In the broken version the form would continue processing and leave the user in the main view in a state where that url and all urls afterwards had a parameter (?topic=Business) appended to them. From then on the document.add would no longer work. By moving to a button and using e.preventDefault it now works every time and all the urls remain clear. (no idea why this side effect wedged firestore add)

```
    var postOfferElement = document.getElementById('postoffer');
    postOfferElement.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        saveOffer();
    });
```

In saveOffer:

```
  firebase.firestore().collection('offers').add({
    created: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    owner: getUserID(),
    name: getUserName(),
    pic: getProfilePicUrl(),
    completes: 0,
    favs: 0,
    offer: offerText,
    topic: topicText,
    exp: expText
  });
```